# How to check if email format is valid? And two passwords are matching? React Native

Tags: react-native

I made a simple registration form in React Native. I want to check if the email format is valid or not and i want the user to re-enter password and check if the two passwords match each others. I'm new to react native so please let me know how to combine your code with mine.

```
    export class Register extends Component {
     constructor(props) {
         super(props);
         this.state = { 
             email: '',
             password: '',
             name: '',
             lastname: ''
         }
this.onSignUp = this.onSignUp.bind(this)

     }
onSignUp(){
    if(
        this.state.email != '' &&
        this.state.password != '' &&
        this.state.name != '' 
      ){
    const { email, password, name } = this.state;
    firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
    .then((result) => {
        firebase.firestore().collection("Users")
            .doc(firebase.auth().currentUser.uid)
            .set({
                name,
                email
            })
        console.log(result)
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error)
    })
}
else{
    alert("Please fill the empty spaces!");
}

}

    render() { form body }
```

Answer (score 0):

This might help: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61933102/sending-verification-email-with-firebase-and-react-native\](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61933102/sending-verification-email-with-firebase-and-react-native%5C)
I don't think there's a way to check if something is valid email except for parsing the string a checking if it contains the @ and the .com/org/etc.. in the correct places except for sending and email and waiting for a no response.